# Swisscom Cloud SSL certificate

Tags: swisscomdev

We're rolling out some simple static web sites onto the Swisscom CloudFoundry cloud, and want to enable SSL for the sites.

Our product manager is not happy with the scapp.io or applicationweb.io names, and we want to be able to add SSL certificates for our domain, e.g "www.swisscom.io".

How do achieve this, given the fact that we're users and not administrators and don't have access to the "Operations Manager" tool? This question is specifically about the Certificate: The setting up of the domain and DNS is clear.

Comment: Just to say where I am with my thinking on this: Perhaps someone can confirm or deny. So, this is on the **public** cloud, and the HA proxy is common for all application instances. I probably **don't want** to install my site's certificate, because that means that any other developer could publish applications with my host's name on it. What I really want is a private cloud environment with my certificates in it. Am I starting to think properly now?

Answer (score 2):

SSL certificates from Let’s Encrypt are now available on the Swisscom Application Cloud: [SSL Secure Routes](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide-sc/deploy-apps/certificates.html)

Answer (score 1):

The cloud guys can probably help you out more here, but one option would be to use: https://www.cloudflare.com/

I was able to use the cloudflare SSL certificate to secure the traffic to and from my application without having to upload a certificate or use the "Operations Manager" tool.

Cheers,

Allan.

Comment: Thanks Allan, it would work, and I'll keep that as a backup option, but I'd prefer to find the "correct" way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using an existing VM on https://www.digitalocean.com to serve as a reverse proxy (see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension#enabling-ssl-reverse-proxy-support, e.g.). It works, but it's not very elegant.