# Setting SSL certificate for private domain in Swisscom Cloudfoundry?

Tags: https, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

The Swisscom documentation on Routes and Domains acknowledges that

> If you use domain forwarding, SSL requests to the root domain may fail if the SSL certificate only matches the subdomain.

However, there seems to be no way to add a custom SSL/TLS certificate to your domain. Am I missing some hidden settings? Other Cloudfoundry providers have special interfaces for installing certificates in their web admin applications. So when trying to use a private domain for a Route to an app there and you access it via HTTPS, as expected, you get an invalid certificate error (because you get served the scapp.io certificate).

So: How do I set up a custom SSL certificate for a private domain in Swisscom’s Cloudfoundry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL certificates from Let’s Encrypt are now available on the Swisscom Application Cloud: [SSL Secure Routes](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide-sc/deploy-apps/certificates.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) that provides such a service.

See also [Swisscom Cloud SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154865/swisscom-cloud-ssl-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Swisscom Application Cloud team is aware of this issue. 
We are currently busy preparing proper answer to it.
Please expect some communication concerning this subject in the next issue of Application Cloud monthly newsletter.
All registered Application Cloud user should receive it. If you are not yet among them - please sign up!

Comment: And when will that monthly newsletter come out? If it’s gonna be the end of May, that would be a little late.